# Besides NLTK, what is the best information retrieval library for Python?

Tags: python, information-retrieval, text-mining

For use to analyze documents on the Internet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, [R](http://www.r-project.org) has many tools available for text mining, and it's easy to [integrate with Python using RPy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html).

Have a look at the [Natural Language Processing view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).  In particular, look at the `tm` package.  Here are some relevant links:

- Paper about the package in the Journal of Statistical Computing: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper.  The paper includes a nice example of an analysis of the R-devel
  mailing list (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/) newsgroup postings from 2006.
- Package homepage: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html
- Look at the introductory vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf

In addition, R provides many tools for parsing HTML or XML.  Have [a look at this question for an example using the `RCurl` and `XML` packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).

Answer (score 3):

Could you please provide more information why NLTK is insufficient or what features you need to consider some framework the "best"?

Nevertheless, there is the builtin [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) lexical parsing library.

There is also a recent book on the subject, [Natural Language Processing with Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516495). It looks like at least part of it covers NLTK.

You might also want to look at this list of tutorials and libraries on the [awaretek](http://www.awaretek.com/tutorials.html#linguistics) website, which also points to the [NLQ.py](http://gurno.com/adam/nlq/) framework.

[Natural Language Processing with Python http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41NBqj7NyGL._BO2.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41NBqj7NyGL._BO2.jpg)

Comment: It does use NLTK throughout and is a great book if you want to do NLP with python, just like the name says! :)