# How can I read and parse the contents of a webpage in R

Tags: html, r, screen-scraping, html-content-extraction

I'd like to read the contents of a URL (e.q., http://www.haaretz.com/) in R. I am wondering how I can do it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not really sure how you want to process that page, because it's really messy.  As we [re-learned in this famous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), it's not a good idea to do regex on html, so you will definitely want to parse this with the XML package.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
webpage <- getURL("http://www.haaretz.com/")
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
# parse the tree by tables
x <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table", xmlValue)  
# do some clean up with regular expressions
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
x <- gsub("\t","",x)
x <- sub("^[[:space:]]*(.*?)[[:space:]]*$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
x <- x[!(x %in% c("", "|"))]
```

This results in a character vector of mostly just webpage text (along with some javascript):

```
> head(x)
[1] "Subscribe to Print Edition"              "Fri., December 04, 2009 Kislev 17, 5770" "Israel Time:Â 16:48Â (EST+7)"           
[4] "Â Â Make Haaretz your homepage"          "/*check the search form*/"               "function chkSearch()"
```

Comment: OOOhhhhh wow ... I am scrapping a dynamic website and I did everything in the past 7-8 hours and was not able to do it - This one worked for me. Life savior

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet may be the XML package -- see for example this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).

Comment: But how can get rid of the html tags properly. I know I can write a RegEx expression but is there any package that make the coding less dramatic!

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for R. But maybe python+beautifullsoup is the way forward here? Then do your analysis with R you have scraped the screen with beautifullsoup?