# Create a corpus with a single file (webpage)

Tags: file, r

I want to read a single file (the file is a html document) from my computer and store it in a Corpus (I'm using the package `tm`).

Do you have any solution to do that?

Here is what I tried :

```
data<-read.csv(fileName)
c2<-Corpus(VectorSource(data))
```

it mostly works, but I sometime get the error : more columns than column names

I guess I'm not supposed to use `read.csv` for a webpage, as I didn't find a better solution.

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Check out [this previous question on extracting text from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195522/is-there-a-simple-way-in-r-to-extract-only-the-text-elements-of-an-html-page).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A webpage definitely does not conform to the specifications that a CSV should.  Instead you probably want to use the `readHTMLTable` function from the XML package.

---

This is grabbing from an actual webpage but it should be the same idea

```
file <- "http://xkcd.com/"
dat <- readLines(file)
c2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(dat))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see how am I supposed to create a corpus with the result of readHTMLTable. Would you mind giving me an example please ?

Comment: @user1278743 Just to clarify, you're specifically looking for the text of the HTML page, right?  You don't really need to extract the page's tables for your corpus, correct?

Comment: @user1278743 Ah I see - What would you like returned?  Just the text displayed?  The html tags as well?  Can you provide more details about what you expect to be returned.

Comment: yes, i want the text, with the html tags and stuff. I want to put the entire text, in a corpus.