# how to scrape text from a HTML body

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've never scraped.  Would it be straightforward to scrape the text in the main, big gray box only from the link below (starting with header `SRUS43 KMSR 271039`, ending with `.END`)? My end goal is to basically have three tidy columns of data from all that text: the five digit codes, the values in inches, and the basin elevation descriptions, so any pointers with processing the text format are welcome, too.

https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/shef_archive/index.html?rfc=cnrfc&product=swe&year=2019&month=3&day=27&hour=6

thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way in R to extract only the text elements of an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195522/is-there-a-simple-way-in-r-to-extract-only-the-text-elements-of-an-html-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading in the text is fairly easy (see @DiceBoyT answer). Cleaning up the format for three columns is a bit more involved. Below could use some clean-up (especially with the regex), but it gets the job done:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

text <- read_html("https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/shef_archive/index.html?rfc=cnrfc&product=swe&year=2019&month=3&day=27&hour=6") %>% 
  html_node(".notes") %>% 
  html_text() 

df <- tibble(txt = read_lines(text))

df %>%
  mutate(
    row = row_number(),
    with_code = str_extract(txt, "^[A-z0-9]{5}\\s+\\d+(\\.)?\\d"),
    wo_code = str_extract(txt, "^:?\\s+\\d+(\\.)?\\d") %>% str_extract("[:digit:]+\\.?[:digit:]"),
    basin_desc = if_else(!is.na(with_code), lag(txt, 1), NA_character_) %>% str_sub(start = 2)
  ) %>% 
  separate(with_code, c("code", "val"), sep = "\\s+") %>% 
  mutate(
    combined_val = case_when(
      !is.na(val) ~ val,
      !is.na(wo_code) ~ wo_code,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ) %>% as.numeric
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(combined_val)) %>%
  mutate(
    code = zoo::na.locf(code),
    basin_desc = zoo::na.locf(basin_desc)
  ) %>%
  select(
    code, combined_val, basin_desc
  )
#> # A tibble: 643 x 3
#>    code  combined_val basin_desc               
#>    <chr>        <dbl> <chr>                    
#>  1 ACSC1          0   San Antonio Ck - Sunol   
#>  2 ADLC1          0   Arroyo De La Laguna      
#>  3 ADOC1          0   Santa Ana R - Prado Dam  
#>  4 AHOC1          0   Arroyo Honda nr San Jose 
#>  5 AKYC1         41   SF American nr Kyburz    
#>  6 AKYC1          3.2 SF American nr Kyburz    
#>  7 AKYC1         42.2 SF American nr Kyburz    
#>  8 ALQC1          0   Alamo Canal nr Pleasanton
#>  9 ALRC1          0   Alamitos Ck - Almaden Res
#> 10 ANDC1          0   Coyote Ck - Anderson Res 
#> # ... with 633 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm probably asking too much, but what if I wanted the `basin_desc` to be the elevation description instead of the location description, such as: `Entire Basin`, `Base to 5000'`, `5000' to Top`, etc?

Comment: For the comment above, I worked through each step of @JasonAizkalns and came up successfully with: `df <- df %>% mutate(elevation_zone = gsub(".*(inches))","",txt)) `

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward to scrape with `rvest`:

```
library(rvest)

text <- read_html("https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/shef_archive/index.html?rfc=cnrfc&product=swe&year=2019&month=3&day=27&hour=6") %>% 
  html_node(".notes") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: glad to hear, though I'm getting  `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Could not resolve host: www.nohrsc.noaa.gov
Calls: %>% -> eval -> eval -> read_html -> read_html.default
Execution halted`

Comment: Try restarting R and running the code, it works fine for me with a fresh R session.