# How can I get dynamic html tags using rvest?

Tags: r

I want to read the next pet button link [from here](https://www.petfinder.com/dog/lilly-45365714/gu/yigo/guam-animals-in-need-gu01/) so that I can go on scraping the next page.

I can find the link about next pet in the source code of this web page
but whatever I tried just can't read the `<a>` tag with the link I need.

I already tried using `rvest` because from the source code I found that next pet button is class `.pdpNav-inner-btn`

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

nextpage <- read_html('https://www.petfinder.com/dog/lilly-45365714/gu/yigo/guam-animals-in-need-gu01/') %>%  
  html_nodes('.pdpNav-inner-btn') %>%
  html_attrs()
```

but all I got were empty list or empty char array.

I also tried reading the whole html and just looking for `Next Pet` string:

```
url<-GET('https://www.petfinder.com/dog/lilly-45365714/gu/yigo/guam-animals-in-need-gu01/')
  url <- content(url, as="text")
gregexpr('Next Pet',url)
```

but I still got nothing.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I can't find the next button on the page nor `.pdpNav-inner-btn` class. Do you need to be logged in for that?

Comment: no I didn't login either . I read the source code of the html to find .pdpNav-inner-btn class it was in <a></a> tag

Comment: Hi 黃城恩, pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746256/extract-links-from-webpage-using-r), if it helps somehow.