# Read HTML Table in R - Troubleshooting

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have seen a number of posts here that describe how to parse HTML tables using the XML package.  That said, I have got my code to work except that my first data row gets read in as my column names.

My code is taken from the answser at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package)

How can I get around this?

Many thanks,

Brock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the XML package documentation for "readHTMLTable":

```
header: either a logical value indicating whether the table has
          column labels, e.g. the first row or a ‘thead’, or
          alternatively a character vector giving the names to use for
          the resulting columns.
```

So running the same command but passing in `header=FALSE` should do what you want. Alternatively, if you have a vector of column names you want to use instead, you can use `header=your_vector_of_column_names` to set the column names instead of setting them to empty strings.