# Selecting specific XML nodes in R?

Tags: xml, r

I am using `XML` package in `R` to parse a `XML` file that has the following structure.

```
 <document id="Something" origId="Text">
    <sentence id="Something" origId="thisorig" text="Blah Blah.">
    <special id="id.s0.i0" origId="1" e1="en1" e2="en2" type="" directed="True"/>
    </sentence>
     <sentence id="Something" origId="thisorig" text="Blah Blah.">
      </sentence>
</document>
```

I want to select the nodes having `</special>` tag in them in one variable and the nodes without the `</special>` tag in other variable.

Is it possible to do it with `R` any pointers/answers will be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package

Comment: @Chase: No this is not I am looking for, still stuck with the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a few more cases to test for exceptions:

```
<document id="Something" origId="Text">
    <sentence id="Something" origId="thisorig" text="Blah Blah.">
    <special id="id.s0.i0" origId="1" e1="en1" e2="en2" type="" directed="True"/>
    </sentence>
    <sentence id="Else" origId="thatorig" text="Blu Blu.">
      <special id="id.s0.i1" origId="1" e1="en1" e2="en2" type="" directed="True"/>
    </sentence>
     <sentence id="Something" origId="thisorig" text="Blah Blah.">
       <notso id = "hallo" />
      </sentence>
     <sentence id="Something no sentence" origId="thisOther" text="Blah Blah.">
      </sentence>
</document>

library(XML)
doc = xmlInternalTreeParse("sentence.xml")
hasSentence = xpathApply(doc, "//sentence/special/..")
xpathApply(doc, "/document/sentence[not(child::special)]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the xml tree, use xpath to specify the location of the nodes.

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("test.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
special_nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "/document//special")
```

Comment: How would he get the non-special nodes with this approach?