# Getting stock news data from google in R

Tags: r, google-finance, quantitative-finance, quantmod

I can use quantmod to get historical data and close-to-realtime quotes for stocks.  I can also use quantmod to get financials data from Google. Are there any existing R packages that would let me grab [Google's news feed](http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=NYSE%3aSPY) for a given stock?

If not, is there a package for reading and parsing [RSS feeds](http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=NYSE%3aSPY&output=rss) in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own function to do this, using XML and xts.  [I posted it as a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761576/improving-a-function-to-get-stock-news-data-from-google-in-r), because I think it could be improved.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, RSS is after all XML, so use the [XML](http://cran.r-project.org/package=XML) package.

Comment: And look here for some good nuggets of info on using said package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package

Answer (score 2):

There's also a (not yet on CRAN) package that does some of the nitty gritty of parsing RSS feeds (and Atom) for you - nothing fancy, just some of the basic cleaning, normalization between the RSS and Atom spec, etc.

You can grab it from https://github.com/noahhl/r-does-rss

(full disclosure, I wrote it)