# Extracting html tables from website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to use XML, RCurl package to read some html tables of the following URL
http://www.nse-india.com/marketinfo/equities/cmquote.jsp?key=SBINEQN&symbol=SBIN&flag=0&series=EQ#

Here is the code I am using

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
options(RCurlOptions = list(useragent = "R"))
url <- "http://www.nse-india.com/marketinfo/equities/cmquote.jsp?key=SBINEQN&symbol=SBIN&flag=0&series=EQ#"
wp <- getURLContent(url)
doc <- htmlParse(wp, asText = TRUE) 
docName(doc) <- url
tmp <- readHTMLTable(doc)
## Required tables 
tmp[[13]]
tmp[[14]]
```

If you look at the tables it has not been able to parse the values from the webpage.
I guess this due to some javascipt evaluation happening on the fly.
Now if I use "save page as" option in google chrome(it does not work in mozilla) 
and save the page and then use the above code i am able to read in the values.

But is there a work around so that I can read the table of the fly ?
 It will be great if you can help.

Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package duplicate?

Comment: Hi Brandon, I guess it is not, if you run the code I wrote you will see I am getting the required table but not the values associated with the fields, due to what I guess is some javascipt issue

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with it, I couldn't find anything that downloads the page in the way that's necessary. The only recommendation that I can make is to setup a chron job to download the page with something like wget and then have R target the downloaded local file.

Comment: Although, that might not work either and you may have to implement some type of web scraping software prior to moving it into R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they're building the page using javascript by accessing http://www.nse-india.com/marketinfo/equities/ajaxGetQuote.jsp?symbol=SBIN&series=EQ and parsing out some string. Maybe you could grab that data and parse it out instead of scraping the page itself.

Looks like you'll have to build a request with the proper referrer headers using cURL, though. As you can see, you can't just hit that ajaxGetQuote page with a bare request.

You can probably read the appropriate headers to put in by using the Web Inspector in Chrome or Safari, or by using Firebug in Firefox.