# Web Scraping a table that has inline pictures

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape this table titled [Battle Styles](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Styles_(TCG)#Set_lists) into a dataframe.
https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Styles_(TCG)#Set_lists

The problem is that many of the rows contain images with vital information which isn't being picked up in rvest.

The table should look like this:

```
No.     Card name   Type    Rarity
001/163 Bellsprout  Grass   Common
002/163 Weepinbell  Grass   Uncommon
003/163 Victreebel  Grass   Rare
004/163 Cacnea      Grass   Common
005/163 Cacturne    Grass   Uncommon
006/163 KricketuneV Grass   Ultra-Rare Rare
007/163 Cherubi     Grass   Common
008/163 Cherrim     Grass   Rare Holo
009/163 Carnivine   Grass   Uncommon
010/163 Durant      Grass   Uncommon
```

and this table ^^ is what I'm able to get if I copy the table and paste it into notepad.

However mine does not contain any information from the pictures. It looks like this:

```
     # A tibble: 184 x 6
   No.     Image `Card name` Type  Rarity Promotion
   <chr>   <lgl> <chr>       <chr> <lgl>  <chr>    
 1 001/163 NA    Bellsprout  ""    NA     Promotion
 2 002/163 NA    Weepinbell  ""    NA     Promotion
 3 003/163 NA    Victreebel  ""    NA     Promotion
 4 004/163 NA    Cacnea      ""    NA     Promotion
 5 005/163 NA    Cacturne    ""    NA     Promotion
 6 006/163 NA    Kricketune  ""    NA     Promotion
 7 007/163 NA    Cherubi     ""    NA     Promotion
 8 008/163 NA    Cherrim     ""    NA     Promotion
 9 009/163 NA    Carnivine   ""    NA     Promotion
10 010/163 NA    Durant      ""    NA     Promotion
```

The information necessary from pictures is in the alt-text, so I feel like the solution should be straight forward, but I can't figure out how to get it.

Here's my code:

```
library(rvest)

BattlestylesURL <- "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Styles_(TCG)"

temp <- BattlestylesURL %>% 
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes("table")

html_table(temp[16], fill = TRUE)
```

I think the biggest headache is that some columns combine images and text and I'm trying to have a dataframe with information from both in the same column. For example, the "Card Name" of row 6 is Kricketune V. 'Kricketune' is text, but the "V" is a picture.

I feel like there should be a simple way of doing it but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Would greatly appreciate help!

The examples I've found have been similar:
[Scraping Wikipedia HTML table with images, text, and blank cells with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808008/scraping-wikipedia-html-table-with-images-text-and-blank-cells-with-r?rq=1) however, I couldn't figure out how to apply this to this situation because I'm trying to keep the text that was in the row too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the table first then update those columns. You can use `ifelse` for the `Type` column as the value you want can either be in the `th` or the child `img` where present. The interesting bit is in using the right css selectors so as to match only the relevant nodes to update the table with.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

page <- read_html("https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Styles_(TCG)#Set_lists")

df <- page %>%
  html_node(".multicol .roundy tr:nth-child(2) table") %>%
  html_table(fill = T)

df <- subset(df, No. != "") %>% select(-c(Image))

df$Rarity <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) tr table td:nth-child(5) a") %>%
  html_attr("title")
   
df$Type <- map(page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) tr tr:nth-child(n+2) th:nth-child(4)"), function(x) {
  var_node <- x %>%
    html_node("img") %>%
    html_attr("alt")
  ifelse(is.na(var_node), x %>% html_text(trim = T), var_node)
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much QHarr, it pretty much answered it! Really appreciate it. I'm still a bit confused about how to use the ifelse for the type column but will have a bit more of an investigation.

Comment: The ifelse is because type is not always held in an alt attribute of a child img. In a few cases it is simply in the td element itself. If you x %>%
    html_node("img") %>%
    html_attr("alt") where it does not exist, it returns na, which you can then handle with the ifelse to instead return the td %>% html_text