# Pulling historic analyst opinions from yahoo finance in R

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, yahoo-finance

Yahoo Finance has [data on historic analyst opinions](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?s=GOOG) for stocks.  I'm interested in pulling this data into R for analysis, and here is what I have so far:

```
getOpinions <- function(symbol) {
    require(XML)
    require(xts)
    yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?"
    tables <- readHTMLTable(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", symbol, sep = ""), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    Data <- tables[[11]]
    Data$Date <- as.Date(Data$Date,'%d-%b-%y')
    Data <- xts(Data[,-1],order.by=Data[,1])
    Data
}

getOpinions('AAPL')
```

I'm worried that this code will break if the position of the table (currently 11) changes, but I can't think of an elegant way to detect which table has the data I want.  I tried [the solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package/1849388#1849388), but it doesn't seem to work for this problem.

Is there a better way to scrape this data that is less likely to break if yahoo re-arranges their site?

edit: it looks like there's already a package ([fImport](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fImport/index.html)) out there to do this.

```
library(fImport)
yahooBriefing("AAPL")
```

Here is their solution, which doesn't return an xts object, and will probably break if the page layout changes (the yahooKeystats function in fImport is already broken):

```
function (query, file = "tempfile", source = NULL, save = FALSE, 
    try = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.null(source)) 
        source = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?s="
    if (try) {
        z = try(yahooBriefing(query, file, source, save, try = FALSE))
        if (class(z) == "try-error" || class(z) == "Error") {
            return("No Internet Access")
        }
        else {
            return(z)
        }
    }
    else {
        url = paste(source, query, sep = "")
        download.file(url = url, destfile = file)
        x = scan(file, what = "", sep = "\n")
        x = x[grep("Briefing.com", x)]
        x = gsub("</", "<", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("/", " / ", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" class=.yfnc_tabledata1.", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" align=.center.", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" cell.......=...", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" border=...", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" color=.red.", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub(" color=.green.", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<.>", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<td>", "@", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<..>", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<...>", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<....>", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<table>", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<td nowrap", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("<td height=....", "", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = gsub("&amp;", "&", x, perl = TRUE)
        x = unlist(strsplit(x, ">"))
        x = x[grep("-...-[90]", x, perl = TRUE)]
        nX = length(x)
        x[nX] = gsub("@$", "", x[nX], perl = TRUE)
        x = unlist(strsplit(x, "@"))
        x[x == ""] = "NA"
        x = matrix(x, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 9)[, -c(2, 4, 6, 8)]
        x[, 1] = as.character(strptime(x[, 1], format = "%d-%b-%y"))
        colnames(x) = c("Date", "ResearchFirm", "Action", "From", 
            "To")
        x = x[nrow(x):1, ]
        X = as.data.frame(x)
    }
    X
}
```

Comment: What happened to yahooBriefing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack you can use. Inside your function, add the following

```
# GET THE POSITION OF TABLE WITH MAX. ROWS
position = which.max(sapply(tables, NROW))
Data     = tables[[position]]
```

This will work as long as the longest table on the page is what you seek.

If you want to make it a little more robust, here is another approach

```
# GET POSITION OF TABLE CONTAINING RESEARCH FIRM IN ITS NAMES
position = sapply(tables, function(tab) 'Research Firm' %in% names(tab))
Data     = tables[position == TRUE]
```