# R xml encountering and dealing with html entities in an xml file

Tags: html, xml, r, xml-parsing, html-entities

Hello R's XML package users,

I am encountering a weird bug while parsing XML. It has to do with encountering HTML entities like mdash and ndash while parsing XML files.

This is the code I use:

```
InText = readLines(xmlFileName,n=-1)
Text = xmlValue(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(InText,trim=FALSE)))
```

I am currently eliminating these entities like mdash and ndash using the following

```
InText = gsub("\\&mdash"," ",InText);
InText = gsub("\\&ndash"," ",InText);
```

But this can really tedious, as I see the list of possible HTML.4.0 entity list.

Any ideas on how I can eliminate these while parsing the XML files

Thanks a lot for your help and ideas
Shivani

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove all named HTML entities, use a regex:

```
library("XML")

InText <- "<html>\
<head>\
    <title>Test &amp; Test again</title>\
</head>\
    <body>Hello &nbsp; world</body>\
</html>"

InText <- gsub("\\&[^;]+;","",InText)

Text <-  xmlValue(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(InText,trim=FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try readHTML in the XML package; it has robust methods that can handle quite a few of these cases. See also [Scraping html tables into R data frames using the XML package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package) .