# unescaping parsed strings produced by R XML package?

Tags: r, xml-parsing, escaping

I have been cribbing off of the very helpful responses on [Scraping html tables into R data frames using the XML package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package) to scrape some html off the web and work with it in R.

The XML package seems to be pretty thorough about escaping non-alphabetic characters in text strings.  Is there a simple way in XML or some other package that would reverse some/all of the character escaping that passing my data through XML did?  I started to do it myself, but after encountering cases like 'Representative JoaquÃƒÂ­n Castro' thought 'there must be a better solution...'

Just for clarity, using the XML package to parse this HTML

```
 library(XML)
 apos_str <- c("<b>Tim O'Reilly</b>")
 apos_str.parsed <- htmlTreeParse(apos_str, error=function(...){})
 apos_str.parsed$children$html[[1]][[1]]
```

would produce

```
 <b>Tim O&apos;Reilly</b>
```

And I'd ideally like a function or package that would search for that

```
&apos;
```

and turn it back into

```
'<b>Tim O'Reilly</b>'
```

**Edit** To clarify, from the comments below, I get how to do this for the particular case of apostrophes, or any other character I see in my data.  What I'm looking for is a package where someone has worked this out more generally.

Research I've done so far:

-Read everything I could find in the XML [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf) on escaping.

-Looked for a promising package on the CRAN [NLP page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

-did a search for 'unescape [R]' and 'reverse escape [R]' here on SO.
Wasn't able to make any headway so thought I would bring the question here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand the difficulty. String processing for replacements are done with the base regex functions: sub, gsub, regexpr, gregexpr

```
?sub # the same help page will also discuss 'gsub'
txt <- '<b>Tim O&apos;Reilly</b>'
sub("\\&apos;", "'", txt)
[1] "<b>Tim O'Reilly</b>"
```

If you had a list of values that occur between "&" and ";" you could split on those and then recombine. I suppose it is possible that you were hoping someone had already done that. You should clarify what level of abstraction you were hoping to achieve.

EDIT: 
A blogger discusses the specific case of "&apos"  http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/07/01/the_curse_of_apos/

I've done some further  research of my own. Those are not properly called "escapes" but rather "named entities". I cannot find any references to them in the rhelp archives. I have downloaded the XML listing from the w3.org website that defines these "enities" and am trying to convert to a tabular form that would support search and replace. But your comment about 'Representative JoaquÃƒÂ­n Castro' has me puzzled. the odd characters are not in the form "$#xxx", so  ........... what exactly are you asking for? Please post a suitable test case with the expected output.

EDIT 2:  The was a basically identical question from Michael Friendly that just got answered by David Carlson on Rhelp. Here's the link to the posting on the Rhelp archives:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/321478.html

He's already done a better job than I had on creating a translation table and has included code to march through html text. (and a bonus... he included `&apos`). And a next-day followup from Michael Friendly has wrapped the process up in a function. You can follow the link on the Archives page.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear.  The apostrophe one is pretty simple and I can do it through sub or stringr; I was basically wondering if there was a better solution that would process many different escaped characters (including, say ' JoaquÃƒÂ­n Castro' -> 'Joaquín Castro')

Comment: so, exactly, I'm asking if someone has already done this, including weird edge cases that I wouldn't immediately think of.  I obviously did a bad job of making this clear in the question.