# specified table extraction with xpath

Tags: r, xpath

I want to extract a table from web http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team

```
library(XML)
baseURL <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team"
xmltext <- htmlParse(baseURL)
xmltable <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//table[.//tbody//tr//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']]")
```

Here is the xpath :`"//table[.//tbody//tr//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']]"`

neither

```
xmltable <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//table[.//tbody//tr//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']]")
```

nor

```
xmltable <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//table[//tbody//tr//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']]")
```

Can get the specified table. How can I write xpath expression?
Please see the attchment .
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package

Comment: yes , it is a good example ,i want to understand well，my ideal is not the same as that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `..` to get the parent element in your xpath: `//table[@class='wikitable']//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']/../../..`

To get the table you could use `XML::readHTMLTable`:

```
library(XML)
baseURL <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team"
xmltext <- htmlParse(baseURL)

## grep correct table
tableNode <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//table[@class='wikitable']//th//a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']/../../..")[[1]]

## convert XMLNode into data.frame
concacafTable <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## format table (remove useless "Gold Cup"-header (row 1) and set right header (row 2)
colnames(concacafTable) <- concacafTable[2, ]
concacafTable <- concacafTable[-c(1,2),]
concacafTable
#   Year       Round GP W D L GF GA
#3  1996  Runners-up  4 3 0 1 10  3
#4  1998 Third Place  5 2 2 1  6  2
#5  2003  Runners-up  5 3 0 2  6  4                                                 
#6 Total        3/11 14 8 2 4 22  9
```

Answer (score 0):

i find two  secretaries in parsing the web too,

1.tbody can't be known

```
tableNode <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//tbody")
```

can get nothing.there are many tbody element in the web ,none of them were be recognized as formal element.

2.to  directly get the table,not to use  the concept of parent element

```
tableNode <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//table[@class='wikitable'][./tr/th/a[@title='CONCACAF Gold Cup']]") can work too.
```