# readLines function lost contents display a small part

Tags: r

Why I can't I read the downloaded file in `readLines`? How can I read it?

```
url="http://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
txt=download.file(url,destfile="stock")
> file1=readLines("stock",encoding="big5")
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("stock", encoding = "big5") :
invalid input found on input connection 'stock'
2: In readLines("stock", encoding = "big5") :
incomplete final line found on 'stock'
> file1=readLines("stock",encoding="gbk")
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gbk") :
invalid input found on input connection 'stock'
2: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gbk") :
incomplete final line found on 'stock'
> file1=readLines("stock",encoding="gb2132")
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gb2132") :
invalid input found on input connection 'stock'
2: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gb2132") :
incomplete final line found on 'stock'
> file1=readLines("stock",encoding="gb18030")
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gb18030") :
 invalid input found on input connection 'stock'
2: In readLines("stock", encoding = "gb18030") :
incomplete final line found on 'stock'
```

The file contains only part of contents, many of contents lost, why?

Comment: I realize that English may not be your first language, but please in the future try to pay more attention to your spelling and grammar.

Comment: Try opening the file 'stock' in a text editor.  It's possible this is an encoding issue: try reading the help page for readlines to see how to control encoding.  To understand encoding, see any of the thousands of pages about it here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The file contains 18 lines, and my R reads all of these 18 lines. I suspect that you're trying to ignore the difference between a text file and an HTML file. To extract the HTML table, you'll need to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).

Comment: when you download the file ,open it, the  file contains at least 1800 lines.

Comment: Nope, there are precisely 18 lines in that file when it's interpreted as text. The rest is HTML - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Comment: ok ,the stock file is a html file ,now ,i want to read it as a text with  `readLines("stock")`,why i can't?

Comment: You can't read it as a text file because it IS not a text file - see the link in my answer on how to extract data from HTML.