# read html table in R

Tags: html, r, parsing

Im trying to read head2head data from [tennis abstract](http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player.cgi?p=NovakDjokovic&f=ACareerqqs00&view=h2h) webpage in R using package XML.

I want the big h2h table at the bottom,
*css selector*: `html > body > div#main > table#maintable > tbody > tr > td#stats > table#matches.tablesorter`

I have tried following suggestions from [scraping html into r data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).
I believe the difficulty is caused by *table within table*

```
url = "http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player.cgi?p=NovakDjokovic&f=ACareerqqs00&view=h2h"
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

webpage <- getURL(url)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)  #doesnt have the h2h table
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
results <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table[@class='tablesorter']/tr/td", xmlValue)  # gives NULL

tables <- readHTMLTable( url,stringsAsFactors=T) # has 4 tables, not the desired one
```

I'm new to html parsing, so please bear with.

Comment: I think the table is build using java script. Use [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) to scape it. You'll find plenty of examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rselenium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most efficient but it will do the job.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

tennis.url <- "http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player.cgi?p=NovakDjokovic&f=ACareerqqs00&view=h2h"

checkForServer(); startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()

remDrv$navigate(tennis.url)
tennis.html <- html(remDrv$getPageSource()[[1]])

remDrv$close()

H2Hs <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes(".h2hclick") %>% html_text %>% as.numeric
Opponent <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes("#matches a") %>% html_text
Country <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes("a+ span") %>% html_text %>% gsub("[^(A-Z)]", "", .)
W <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes("#matches td:nth-child(3)") %>% .[-1] %>% html_text %>% as.numeric
L <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes("#matches td:nth-child(4)") %>% .[-1] %>% html_text %>% as.numeric
Win.Prc <- tennis.html %>% html_nodes("#matches td:nth-child(5)") %>% .[-1] %>% html_text
```

And so on for the rest. You just need to increment the # in `nth-child(#)` and then create a data frame.

Comment: Im getting the following error:   remDrv$open()  gives error : 
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Undefined error in RCurl call.
Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :

Comment: It started working after I did the following from command prompt.   java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar