# Scraping data from different webpages using R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping

I want to be able to take data from numerous tables hosted on a website. The catch is that they are all on different webpages.

As an example, [here are links](https://www.doogal.co.uk/ElectoralConstituencies.php) to the electoral constituencies of the UK. As you can see, all of the constituencies are there and each links through to a separate page. If you go to an individual constituency page, you have the option of downloading a .csv file of the postcodes, or there is an html page.

I have found numerous explanations of how to do this when the various data sources are all on the same page, but is it possible to do something that will create a datafile that combines the postcode data from each area?

For example, I have got the data for the first area, Aberavon, using the following code, which I identified a version of in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
install.packages("rlist")
library(rlist)

theurl <- getURL("https://www.doogal.co.uk/ElectoralConstituencies.php?constituency=W07000049",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
```

I usually use R so would be good to know how to do it using R but appreciate some other approach might be better suited and am happy to try others. I am quite new to data scraping so if this is really obvious I might not have understood the limitations of the instructions I have read!

Answer (score 0):

You need to roll up your sleeves and apply some elbow grease.

Before I expand on an answer, I did check the site for scraping policies, including the `robots.txt` file. Said file is malformed:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

I *suspect* the owner of the site meant to have a `/` after `Disallow:` but nothing says we can't scrape.

Some libraries we'll need:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
```

I'm using different libraries than you are. If you'd prefer to stick with the `XML` and `RCurl` packages and base R then you'll need to adapt this r wait for another answer.

The following gets the initial page data that we'll mine for links:

```
res <- httr::GET("https://www.doogal.co.uk/ElectoralConstituencies.php")

pg <- httr::content(res, as="parsed")
```

In the event you wanted the CSV of the main page data, here's the URL for it:

```
html_nodes(pg, "li > a[href*='CSV']") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("https://www.doogal.co.uk/%s", .) -> main_csv_url
```

Now we need links to the individual constituencies. I inspected the HTML page content with Chrome Developer Tools to figure out the CSS selectors:

```
constituency_nodes <- html_nodes(pg, "td > a[href*='constituency=']") 
constituency_names <- html_text(constituency_nodes)
constituency_ids <- gsub("^E.*=", "", html_attr(constituency_nodes, "href"))
```

Note that we're only saving off the id's and not the full URLs.

We'll make a helper function to shorten things up. `httr::GET()` let's us behave like a browser would:

```
get_constituency <- function(id) {

  httr::GET(
    url = "https://www.doogal.co.uk/ElectoralConstituenciesCSV.php", 
    query = list(constituency = id)
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  res <- read.csv(text = httr::content(res), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  as_tibble(res)

}
```

And, then call our new function for all the constituencies. The following includes a progress bar for free:

```
pb <- progress_estimated(3)
map_df(constituency_ids[1:3], ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  Sys.sleep(5)

  get_constituency(.x)

}) -> postcodes_df

glimpse(postcodes_df)
## Observations: 10,860
## Variables: 12
## $ Postcode   <chr> "CF33 6PS", "CF33 6PT", "CF33 6PU", "CF33 6RA", "CF33 6R...
## $ In.Use.    <chr> "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "...
## $ Latitude   <dbl> 51.53863, 51.54013, 51.53815, 51.54479, 51.55091, 51.552...
## $ Longitude  <dbl> -3.700061, -3.699713, -3.690541, -3.684888, -3.673475, -...
## $ Easting    <int> 282191, 282219, 282850, 283259, 284066, 284886, 284613, ...
## $ Northing   <int> 183562, 183728, 183493, 184222, 184885, 185007, 183874, ...
## $ Grid.Ref   <chr> "SS821835", "SS822837", "SS828834", "SS832842", "SS84084...
## $ Introduced <chr> "7/1/1995 12:00:00 AM", "1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM", "1/1/198...
## $ Terminated <chr> "", "", "", "", "", "", "4/1/2002 12:00:00 AM", "", "1/1...
## $ Altitude   <int> 45, 47, 46, 76, 76, 131, 61, 27, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8,...
## $ Population <int> 34, NA, 7, 33, 48, 11, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
## $ Households <int> 12, NA, 3, 11, 19, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
```

NOTE:

- I only did 3 iterations since I don't need this data. Remove that limit for your needs.
- Please keep the delay code in there when you do this. You have time and it's their bandwidth & CPU you'd be abusing.
- There's enough data in the code above to add in the constituency name as a data frame field, but that's work left to the reader